# Justify align anchors inside HTML <div>

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 social-icons">
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"><img src="/images/youtube-i.png"></a>
        <a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank"><img src="/images/github-i.png"></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank"><img src="/images/twitter-i.png"></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="/images/facebook-i.png"></a>
        <a href="https://t.me/" target="_blank"><img src="/images/telegram-i.png"></a>
        <a href="https://medium.com/" target="_blank"><img src="/images/m-icn.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I am trying to "justify align" all the social icons. The icons align to center using "text-center" class on "social-icons" "div" and vice versa but "text-justify" class does NOT work.

CSS:

```
.social-icons img{
    margin-right: 7px;
}
.social-icons{
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
.social-icons a{
    display:block;
    width: 16.66%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
.social-icons img:last-child{
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.notify-section .social-icons img{
    width: 40px;
}
```

Can anybody help or assist to achieve required result? https://www.screencast.com/t/fjePINOiv

Comment: Can you add your css

Comment: Screenshot updated. CSS added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `text-align-last: justify;`

```css
.justify-links{
  text-align-last: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="justify-links">
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok let me try this.

Comment: `text-align-last: justify;` is not working on Safari on iPhone. Is there any way you know that it would work there on Safari of iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

You just use `justify-content: space-between;` to get equal space with flex. Try this snippet for your reference.

```css
.justify-links{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="justify-links">
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```